# Video muted only on mobile devices

Tags: html, video

Is there any way of muting video on mobile devices only.  I need to use the autoplay option but on mobile this will only work when the video is muted but i don’t want this on the desktop version

Comment: I presume you are using android but that could be wrong. You do have to edit your question to specify the technologies used i.e. android, windows, linux java e.t.c.

Comment: you could follow specific detection as outlined here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser - or have a test that checks if the video is playing after (say) .25s and if not then mutes it and tries again